# Publish Flutter package to Azure artifacts

Tags: flutter, dart, azure-artifacts

Is anybody has experience with uploading the Flutter package to Azure artifacts and use it as a dependency in another Flutter project, is it even possible? Azure artifacts don't have a prepared solution for it, but maybe options of a universal package is may be used to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually is not posible to storage in artifact repo, but Flutter allows to import directly from git repo https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages